# How to filter a promise with filterFilter in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, filter, ionic-framework

I am a newbie at angularJs and i'm using ionic to build an app.
I have a service with the following return all the notes made by a user. Below:

```
// Promise-based API
    return {
      loadAllNotes: function () {
        return deferredPromise.promise;
      },
      query: function (params) {
        deferredPromise.promise.then(function(data){
          //console.log(filterFilter(data.notes, params)); //CORRECT RESULT
          return filterFilter(data.notes, params);
        });
      }
}
```

i made the `query(params)` function to be able to filter the results. by passing `params`. although when i `console.log()` inside the return function as you see above, i get the desired result. But i can't access that result in my controller.

```
function loadNotes(){
      vm.notes = [].concat(noteService.query({"lead_id":vm.lead.id})); //calling The service function
      console.log(vm.notes); //logs [undefined]
    }
```

I believe there is something i'm missing about handling promises. The filterFilter is working fine i just can't seem to get the result in my controller. Any ideas?

Comment: you are returning `false` from your noteServvice.query

Comment: @webduvet what do you mean? i am returning `filterFilter(data.notes, params)` i `console.log()` the value in the return function and it outputted what i want. i am just not getting it in the controller

Comment: @webduvet i get what you mean now... its too much php that made me code like that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should return the promise itself in your service:

```
query: function (params) {
    return deferredPromise.promise.then(function(data){
        return filterFilter(data.notes, params);
    });
}
```

after which

```
noteService.query({"lead_id":vm.lead.id}).then(function(r){
    vm.notes.push(r);

    console.log(vm.notes);
});
```